# Using HighCharts with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, highcharts, lambda

I am experiencing trouble getting what I am looking for, in respect to setting series for highcharts.  I want to use my table in my database to post the number for the y-axis.

So in my table I have the properties, `ID`, `TeamName`, `TotalWins`.

I only have 2 records

`ID` = 1, `TeamName` = Boston Red Sox, `TotalWins?` = 0 *nullable because the MLB season hasn't started yet*

`ID` = 2, `TeamName` = Baltimore Orioles, `TotalWins?` = 0

Here is my `ActionResult` for my Chart:

```
public ActionResult Chart()
    {
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Pie })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Who Has more Wins?" })
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Source: Sportscenter" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Boston Red Sox", "Baltimore Orioles" },
                Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Teams" }
            })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis
            {
                Min = 0,
                Title = new YAxisTitle
                {
                    Text = "Wins (Game)",
                    Align = AxisTitleAligns.High
                }
            })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return ''+ this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' millions'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
                {
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsBarDataLabels { Enabled = true }
                }
            })
            .SetLegend(new Legend
            {
                Layout = Layouts.Horizontal,
                Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
                VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Top,
                X = -100,
                Y = 100,
                Floating = true,
                BorderWidth = 1,
                BackgroundColor = new BackColorOrGradient(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF")),
                Shadow = true
            })
            .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
            .SetSeries(new[]
            {
                new Series { Data = new Data(new object[] { db.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamName == "Boston Red Sox").Count(x => x.TotalWins) /*where the issue is */ }) },
            });

        return View(chart);
    }
```

cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'bool'

How do I set this lambda expression so that it retrieves the total wins for the boston red sox and then again for the baltimore orioles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.Count(x => x.TotalWins)
```

`Count` either takes no arguments (in which case it returns the total count of the results of the preceding query), or a lambda that returns a boolean expression, in which case it returns a count of items that meet the criteria.

Do you mean `.Sum(x => x.TotalWins)`?